# Django no such column error

Tags: python, sql, django

I have the following code in my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import permalink

class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,db_index=True, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,db_index=True, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(db_index = True, auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('board.Category')
    page = models.ForeignKey('board.Page')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return "/%i/%i" % Page.slug, self.id
```

When I try to add a Post object in the admin page (I configured the admin.py too), I get the following error:

no such column: board_category.name

I did my research and tried dropping the table and doing syncdb again but somehow it still shows this error.

So I listed my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "board_page" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "slug" varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
;
CREATE TABLE "board_category" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "slug" varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
;
CREATE TABLE "board_post" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "title" varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "body" text NOT NULL,
    "post_date" date NOT NULL,
    "category_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "board_category" ("id"),
    "page_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "board_page" ("id")
)
;
CREATE INDEX "board_post_896eb94b" ON "board_post" ("post_date");
CREATE INDEX "board_post_6f33f001" ON "board_post" ("category_id");
CREATE INDEX "board_post_3fb9c94f" ON "board_post" ("page_id");
```

I'm not exactly an expert in SQL but I can clearly see that the board_page.name column exists so I really have no idea why this is giving me an error.

And the strangest thing is that adding another page or category actually works....

--EDIT

```
from django.contrib import admin
from board.models import Page, Post, Category

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #fields = ['name','slug']
    pass
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #fields = ['title','body','category','page']
    pass
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #fields = ['name','slug']
    pass
admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

Comment: and  admin.py you can posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add something to your models and after that you did not sync, this happens.
If you are in beginning for your project, I recommend to remove your db and recreate it and then:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Otherwise use South.
http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

It's interesting but sometimes rebooting the server helps. It worked for me a few times in past.

Answer (score 2):

`syncdb` will only create tables for models which have not yet been installed. It will never issue ALTER TABLE statements to match changes made to a model class after installation.

better use [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to migrate the changes of your models.

first migration with:

```
python manage.py schemamigration yourapp --initial 
python manage.py migrate yourapp
```

other migrations:

```
python manage.py schemamigration yourapp --auto
python manage.py migrate yourapp
```

Comment: Easier than South for simple and basic migration, I advise you to use Django Evolution instead : https://github.com/beanbaginc/django-evolution

Comment: Yeah but I did drop the whole table and recreated it, I think that is still good enough for this (ofc south seems like a better idea) would using south resolve this?

Comment: Your problem seems to be very similar to table not being updated after a change of model (Django isn't able to do that), so it's very likely that South or Django-evolution will solve it.

Comment: You could also try to move your database file out of the folder, run `syncdb` again and see if it works. If it's the case, then it's your database that isn't corresponding to the model.

Comment: What did the migration said? Did it do something? Showed an error?

Comment: No errors. 
 + Added model board.Page
 + Added model board.Category
 + Added model board.Post
Created 0003_initial.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate board
Finished "C:\Users\sdse_temp\workspace\learning\manage.py schemamigration board --initial" execution.